# Function inside __repr__ results in infinite recursion

Tags: python, recursion, repr

I am learning Python, and I tried to code the following.

```
class AttributeDisplay:
    '''Display all attributes of a class in __repr__.
    It can be inherited.'''
    def gatherAttributes(self):
        '''Gather all attributes and concatenate them
        as a string'''
        def getAttributeNameAndValue(key):
            return '[%s] - [%s]' % (key, getattr(self, key))
        return '\n'.join((map(getAttributeNameAndValue, sorted(self.__dict__))))

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Print all attributes'''
        attr = self.gatherAttributes() # omitting () results in infinite recursion
        return '[Class: %s]\n%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
```

I accidentally omitted the parentheses and the attr becomes a function instead of a string. However, when I called the `print(X)`, it gets into the infinite recursion.

The incorrect code is as follows.

```
def __repr__(self):
    '''Print all attributes'''
    attr = self.gatherAttributes # omitting () results in infinite recursion
    return '[Class: %s]\n%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
```

> File "Some Folder/classtools.py", line 18, in __repr__
>
> ```
> return '[Class: %s]\n%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
> ```
>
> [Previous line repeated 244 more times]
>
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I tried to debug but couldn't find the exact reason for this behavior. Even if I left the parentheses by accident, it should print `<function object ...>` right?

Why does it call itself in `__repr__` in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the test code is as follows.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    class TopTest(AttributeDisplay):
        count = 0
        def __init__(self):
            self.attr1 = TopTest.count
            self.attr2 = TopTest.count+1
            TopTest.count += 2

    class SubTest(TopTest):
        pass

    def test():
        t1, t2 = TopTest(), SubTest()
        print(t1)
        print(t2)

    test()
```

Comment: This question is unclear.  How are you getting the recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `repr` of the bound method includes the object it is bound to:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<repr here!>'
...     def x(self): pass
... 
>>> C().x
<bound method C.x of <repr here!>>
>>> str(C().x)
'<bound method C.x of <repr here!>>'
```

Note that I've made a few leaps here -- here they are:

- `'%s' % x` is roughly equivalent to `str(x)`
- When something doesn't define `__str__`, it falls back to `__repr__` (this is the case for the method descriptor)

In retrieving the repr of the class, you end up with this cycle:

- `AttributeDisplay.__repr__` =>
- `AttributeDisplay.gatherAttributes.__repr__` =>
- `AttributeDisplay.__repr__` (repr of the class as part of bound method repr) =>
- ...